# Writing a Text File in memory and saving it with savefiledialog

Tags: c#, memorystream, savefiledialog, textwriter

I am trying to make a text file in memory, add some lines to it and at the end save the file in a text file. I can handle the savedialog part but I dont know how to get the text file from memory. Any help and tips will be appriciated.

What I am doing so far is:

```
//Initialize in memory text writer
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);

tw.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD!");
tw.WriteLine("I WANT TO SAVE THIS FILE AS A .TXT FILE!);
```

**please note**
I will call tw.WriteLine() add more lines in different places so I want to save this at end of program (so this shouldent be wrapped between something like using{} )

**UPDATE**

StringBuilder seems to be a more reliable option for doing this! I get strange cut-outs in my text file when I do it using MemoryStream.

Thanks.

Comment: Why make it in memory first, will that be slow or interactive? Why not just write it to disk once you have the filename from a `FileSaveDialog`?

Comment: Well I have a simple program and dont want to bother with finding a temp path or file, I want this file to be saved only when the operation is complete. then a FileSaveDialog should be come and let user to save the file anywhere he wants.

Comment: I have added a new code to my answer. you can see it. it needs only adding one another line to your code.

Comment: your requirements added to my answer.

Comment: @Sean87 don't really know what is the problem of wrapping the writing to text file part into a `using` statement?

Comment: @Oscar Then I have too put all my methods and stuff inside a using statement it may work but I rather not use that for readability sake.

Comment: @Sean87 You only need the `using` statement when you're writing to the file. Take a look at my answer. Do you really need to have a `MemoryStream`? You can just have a `string` (`StringBuilder`, to be more specific) and append lines to it, and **when you decide to write it to the file** (after the user selects a output file in the `SaveFileDialog`, or when clicks on *Save* button,...), you write that `string` to the file. Then you won't have any problem with the `using`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your best option here would be to write to a `StringBuilder`, and when done, `File.WriteAllText`. If the contents are *large*, you might consider writing directly to the file in the first place (via `File.CreateText(path)`), but for small-to-medium files this should be fine.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine("HELLO WORLD!");
sb.AppendLine("I WANT TO SAVE THIS FILE AS A .TXT FILE!");

File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: @Marc Thanks, my files are note going to be more than 1000 lines, but where this 'foo.txt' will be saved? would it be done with a save dialog this way?

Comment: @Sean87 as written? in the current directory, whatever that is. You can replace that with any path you like - it was purely indicative.

Comment: @Marc and also, add the missing `"` at the end of your 2nd string

Comment: @Farzin - I'll correct it to `path`; the question shows no variable called `dialog`...

Comment: I changed my mind and I am using StringBuilder now since MemoryStreams just mix things up in my text file mainly I got cutted text!! Anyway Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assume your `SaveFileDialog` name is "dialog"

```
File.WriteAllBytes(dialog.FileName, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Your string"));
```

or

```
var text = "Your string";
text += "some other text";
File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, text);
```

also in your own solution you can do this :

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);

tw.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD!");
tw.WriteLine("I WANT TO SAVE THIS FILE AS A .TXT FILE!);

// just add this
File.WriteAllBytes(dialog.FileName, ms.GetBuffer());
```

Comment: your example won't work, because you are appending text to the string `text`, so what you will have at the end is all lines concatenated. Instead you should do something like `text += "some other text" + Environment.NewLine` or just use `\r\n`

Comment: several bugs there; you aren't `using` a few `IDisposable` objects, but more importantly: you are writing the ***oversized*** backing buffer (`GetBuffer()`) without limiting to the actual length of the valid data.

Comment: @Marc He wants simply write some strings in file. there is no need to use IDisposable objects or care size of buffer. do not forget GC ! GC is designed for you and to do not care buffer in this simple situations.

Comment: @FarzinZaker That is not what Marc means. He means _you_ are utilising disposable things _without_ disposing of them! And `GetBuffer`, to quote MSDN, _'Note that the buffer contains allocated bytes which might be unused.'_ So, _you_ are potentially writing invalid data. This is nothing to do with what the user wants, but simply your bad code. There is also a missing quote, breaking your code.

Answer (score 2):

Or, something nigh-on the same as @Marc's answer, but different enough that I think it's worth putting out there as a valid solution:

```
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    writer.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD!");
    writer.WriteLine("I WANT TO SAVE THIS FILE AS A .TXT FILE!");
    File.WriteAllLines(path, writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
}
```

Where `path` is a string representing a valid file system entry path, predefined by you somewhere in the application.

Comment: Disappointement The problem is I will add lines to my memorystream in different places of my program, it is no practical to wrap all my program in a using{} statement

Comment: @Sean87: You can declare the `StringWriter` at whichever scope you desire / require, just be sure to dispose when you are actually done.

Comment: +1 `StringWriter` is definitely the way to go here. It's much easier to use than `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
dlg.DefaultExt = ".text"; // Default file extension
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

// Show save file dialog box
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

// Process save file dialog box results
if (result == true)
{
    // Save document
    using (FileStream file = File.CreateText(dlg.FileName)
    {
        ms.WriteTo(file)
    }
}
```

I haven't worried about whether the file already exists but this should get you close.

You might need a `ms.Seek(SeekOrgin.Begin, 0)` too.

Comment: @Jordell Hmm dont think this would help, what will happen to memorystream part of the code?

Comment: Why do you need it? Just write it straight to the 'FileStream'.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of appending text to the end of a file could be:

```
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.Filename, true)) {
        writer.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

supposing that `text` is the string you need to save into your file.
If you want to append new lines to that string in an easy way, you can do:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Line 1");
sb.AppendLine("Line 2");
```

and the resulting string will be `sb.ToString()`

If you already have a `Stream` object (in your example, a `MemoryStream`), you can do the same but replace the line:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.Filename, true)) {
```

by

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream)) {
```

**Edit:**
About wrapping the statements inside `using`:

Take in count that this is not a problem at all. In my first example, all you will have to do is to keep that `StringBuilder` object, and keep adding lines to it. Once you have what you want, just write the data into a text file.

If you are planning to write more than once to the text file, just clear the `StringBuilder` everytime you write, in order to not get duplicated data.